# Unordered_map weird characters

Tags: c++

```cpp
    std::wifstream ifs("debug.txt");

    std::wstring s;
    std::unordered_map <LPTSTR, LPTSTR> x;
    std::wstring delimiter = L"|";
    size_t pos = 0;
    std::wstring first;  
    std::wstring second;

    while (std::getline(ifs, s)) {   

        pos = s.find(delimiter);
        first = s.substr(0, pos);
        second = s.substr(pos + 1, std::string::npos );

        x[first.data()] = second.data();
    }

    return x;
```

Why the `x` is storing some weird characters at the `return x`?
It happens when the map get the second element.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only storing pointers to `first.data()` and `second.data()` in your map.
If any of them relocate the string data the pointers become dangling and you have UB (undefined behavior) if you try to dereference them. If they don't relocate, you'll have pointers to exactly the same strings in memory. If the map outlives `first` and/or `second` the pointers in the map again becomes dangling and dereferencing them would again cause UB.

Instead, store `std::wstring`s in the map:

```
std::unordered_map <std::wstring, std::wstring> x;

// ...

x[first] = second;        // replaces the value, second, if first already exists

// or

x.emplace(first, second); // do not replace value if first already exists
```

Comment: You should use `basic_string<TCHAR>` instead of `wstring`.

Comment: @zdf Why? OP:s program is clearly using wide chars

Comment: `LPTSTR` is `TCHAR*`. Mixing `TCHAR/wchar_t` is most likely a bug.

Comment: @zdf `LPTSTR` is a `LPWSTR` (`WCHAR*`) if `UNICODE` is defined, but yes, mixing it isn't good. By removing the `LPTSTR` from the map in my answer, the mixing is gone though.

Comment: Agreed. It is one way or the other - OP's choice.